# Getting error while sending an email from my gmail account

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

ERROR: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

MY CODE IS HERE:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rand = r.Next(10000, 90000);
        string from = "srkdbest12@gmail.com";
        string to = "ankushjain358@gmail.com";
        string subject = "User Authentification";
        string body = "click on the below link to AUTHENTICATE your account<br>";
        body += "confirmation.aspx?confirm=" + rand;

        try
        {
            MailMessage mailObject = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("srkdbest12@gmail.com", "MyPassword");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            smtp.Send(mailObject);
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Confirmation email was not sent please try again or Try with a new email id<br>" + ee.Message);
        }
```

Comment: You should preserve the InnerException when rethrowing.

Comment: HTML should never appear in exception messages.

Comment: html is not causing problem here

Comment: That's why I wrote that as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't set `UseDefaultCredentials`.

Comment: by following your answer, i am not getting an exception in my program... but i am not receiving email even now...

Comment: but why these mail are coming in spam ?

Comment: subject is mentioned as subject property of mail object

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

**Update:** as **akiller** correctly suggests, the `UseDefaultCredentials` property should have been set to `false` **before** assigning credentials. This is what makes this code work.

Comment: @SLaks: yes, but it can be overridden in app.config/machine.config

Comment: Having client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; before the line where you set the credentials is what makes it work (in the OPs question this wasn't the case).